Will the lock be removed if we delete the object which monitor is being used
Let's imagine that we have some kind of public global map which entities' monitors are used in synchronized blocks in different methods of other classes. In some moment we remove entities from our collection and garbage collector removes it from application memory.
Sample code is below:
public final class LockTable {
    public static final Map<String, Object> lockers = new HashMap<>();
}

public class FirstClass {
    public void methodWithRemovingKey() throws InterruptedException {
        String someKey = "someKey";

        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            System.out.println("Removing key " + someKey);
            LockTable.lockers.remove(someKey);
        }).start();

        new SecondClass().methodWithSynchronizedBlock(someKey);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new FirstClass().methodWithRemovingKey();
    }
}

public class SecondClass {
    public void methodWithSynchronizedBlock(String key) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Entered methodWithSynchronizedBlock");

        synchronized (LockTable.lockers.computeIfAbsent(key, k-> new Object())) {
            System.out.println("Synchronized object is used " + LockTable.lockers.get(key));
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("Synchronized object was used " + LockTable.lockers.get(key));
        }

        System.out.println("Exit methodWithSynchronizedBlock");
    }
}

If we run main method in the FirstClass we will see that our object used in synchronized block is removed. The program output:
Entered methodWithSynchronizedBlock
Synchronized object is used java.lang.Object@96532d6
Removing key someKey
Synchronized object was used null
Exit methodWithSynchronizedBlock

What will happened with our synchronization if such scenario appears in concurrent environment? Will it be removed?

so long as an object is still being referenced or in use, it wont be GC'd, but in the above, LockTable.lockers.get(key) which prints Synchronized object was used null just means that the lock that was stored in the lock map is now no longer stored in the map.

Your code snippet is hopelessly broken, @AlexanderVolkov. You're doing multithreaded stuff with a simple HashMap, and no proper care of happens-before relationships. You've misunderstood how locks and JMM works, ran 10 miles in the wrong direction, and are now asking highly specific questions. The answer to this question is moot - you need to go back to square one and learn about how locking works. Note that you can't just 'toy around and determine you have a good understanding'. JMM is filled to the brim with 'maybe'. If it works on your machine, that proves nothing.

I do not think that a properly written question, written by someone who clearly wants to learn, deserves being down-voted and closed, no matter how ungrounded the question is. Remember your teacher at school saying "there are no wrong questions", there is a reason for that.

Note: The question as originally posted spoke of "deleting" objects. This answer was written before the question was edited to replace "deleted" with "removed". (And for some weird reason, Stack Overflow has not documented the fact that the question was edited.)

There is no such thing as "deleting an object" in Java.
Just because you removed the object from some map, it does not mean that the object was in any way, shape, or form, deleted.
The object will be "deleted" (correct terminology: "finalized and collected") by the garbage collector when it is not being referenced anymore.
And the object will, of course, continue being referenced for as long as it is locked by the synchronized clause.
